# How to remove unique rows from uploading list postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table with unique columns. I upload dataframes to the table using copy expert and psycopg2 in python. There are duplicate columns in the uploading dataframe. How can I remove the duplicate columns on the uploading dataframe and upload the dataframe?

**Postgres table:**

| email (unique) | verified | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jason@gmail.com | True | 1 |
| eunice@gmail.com | None | 2 |
| sam@outlook.com | True | 3 |
| riley@outlook.com | None | 4 |

List to be uploaded

| email | verified |
| --- | --- |
| jason@gmail.com | None |
| eunice@gmail.com | None |
| benita@outlook.com | None |
| james@outlook.com | None |

Expected table result:

| email (unique) | verified | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jason@gmail.com | True | 1 |
| eunice@gmail.com | None | 2 |
| sam@outlook.com | True | 3 |
| riley@outlook.com | None | 4 |
| benita@outlook.com | None | 5 |
| james@outlook.com | None | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the email field in your DB is unique, you should  make it unique in Postgres:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

When inserting values you can ignore duplicates (like in your example):

```
INSERT INTO your_table (
    email,
    verified
)
VALUES (
    %s,
    %s
)
ON CONFLICT (
    email
)
DO NOTHING;
```

Or you can update the values:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (
    email,
    verified
)
VALUES (
    %s,
    %s
)
ON CONFLICT (
    email
)
DO UPDATE
SET
    verified = %s
;
```

Comment: I use this copy expert command """
    COPY my_table from STDIN WITH
       CSV
        HEADER
        DELIMITER AS ','""" to upload the dataframe. How can I use this insert command with a dataframe in pandas using python?

Answer (score 0):

demo:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=05db3742877c60fc42c4d4ee520d9bfb

---

many inserts expected the serial don't have gap/hole is unrealistic. If you really want no gap serial no, you can have a insert_time_stamp then use row_number to construct the serial no.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_u_info_ins ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
DECLARE
    seq bigint;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'new email: %, new.vertified: %', NEW.email, NEW.verified;
    IF NEW.email IN (
        SELECT
            email
        FROM
            u_infos) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE E'already existed\n';
        RAISE NOTICE 'currval: %\n', currval('u_infos_id_seq'::regclass);
        seq := (
            SELECT
                currval('u_infos_id_seq'::regclass));
        RAISE info E'seq: %\n', seq;
        PERFORM
            pg_catalog.setval('u_infos_id_seq'::regclass, seq, FALSE);
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSE
        RAISE NOTICE 'new email, new record';
        RETURN new;
    END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_u_info_ins BEFORE INSERT ON u_infos FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_u_info_ins ();
```